# Find part of word (factor) in R programming

Tags: r

I am trying to create a column where I categorize into two locations: Headquarters or Fields. Here's a sample data:

```
Location<-c(Unites States Headquarters,Oklahoma City, Dallas, Washington DC, Kansas City)

mutate("Locations"=case_when(grep('Headquarters',Location,ignore.case = FALSE)~'Headquarters'))
```

However, I end up getting an "Error: LHS of case 1 (`grep("Headquarters", Location, ignore.case = FALSE)`) must be a logical vector, not an integer vector." What other function I can use to categorize the location into proper category?

Comment: use grepl (with the "l" at the end), it returns a logical vector (try evaluating only that part of the function so you can see)

Comment: Thank you Elio Diaz. I realized I used the wrong function lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
location <- c("United States Headquarters","Oklahoma City", "Dallas", "Washington DC", "Kansas City")
filtered_loc <- c()

for (val in location) {
  filtered_loc <- c(filtered_loc, if_else(grepl('Headquarters', val), "Headquarters", "Field"))
}
```

`filtered_loc` returns:

```
[1] "Headquarters" "Field"        "Field"        "Field"        "Field"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple `ifelse`statement:

**Data**:

```
location <- c("United States Headquarters","Oklahoma City", "Dallas", "Washington DC", "Kansas City")
```

**Solution**:

```
location2 <- ifelse(grepl("Headquarters", location), "Headquarters", "Field")
```

**Output**:

```
location2
[1] "Headquarters" "Field"        "Field"        "Field"        "Field"
```